# If the prototype of `Object` in JavaScript is null, why can I do Object.toString()?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

All newly created objects (with the exception of objects created using Object.create(null)) contain the object `Object.prototype` in their prototype chain. These newly created objects can call `newObject.toString()` because `toString` is defined on `Object.prototype`.

However, the internal prototype of Object is said to be `null`. If that's the case, why the heck can I do this:

```
Object.toString();
// prints: "function Object() { [native code] }"
```

Perhaps I've answered my own question. Is `toString` also defined on the `Object` constructor function?

Why?!

Comment: But `Object.prototype` isn't null

Comment: `Object` is a constructor function all by itself.  That means it's a Function object with the methods of a Function object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> var obj = Object.create(null);
  undefined
> obj.toString();
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
> Object.toString();
  "function Object() { [native code] }"
```

See, `obj` is created with `null` as the prototype, so when you call `.toString()` on it, error will happen.

But `Object` self is a function, and whose prototype is a Function object, which has the `.toString()` method.

Comment: Ah I forgot that "In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object.". Right. The prototype chain for the constructor actually looks like Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null. Function.prototype actually has its own toString() that overwrites Object.prototype's toString.

Thanks buddy!

Comment: Man that's actually pretty confusing ... particularly the self referential nature of Function inheriting from Function.prototype...

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't have to exist in an object's prototype to be invokable on an object.

Given a simple example...

```
x = {}
x.y = function () { }
```

`y` is not in `x`'s prototype, yet I can use `x.y()`.